# Match response forms in google sheets to the name of the google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, rename

Sorry for the newbie question here; I'm trying to have the name of my response sheet match the name of my form - Right now its just named "form response (1), (2) etc. I have multiple forms that are landing on 1 google sheet, which is exactly what I want, just would love to be able to have the name of the tab be the Google Form name and not "form Response...."

From a previous thread i tried:

```
function writeFormTitle(){
  //Get Form
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  //Get Form's Title
  var formTitle = form.getTitle();

  //Get the Write To Spreadsheet ID where the data will be written to
  var destinationSpreadsheet = form.getDestinationId();

  //Activate that Spreadsheet by the destinationSpreadsheet ID
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheet).getActiveSheet();

  //Find the last column and row
  var writeToColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()+1;
  var writeToRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Write title to Spreadsheet next to submitted data.
  sheet.getRange(writeToRow, writeToColumn, 1, 1).setValue(formTitle);

}
```

But with this its appending the google form name into the last column on EACH sheet.

Any insight would be great!

Comment: Are you going to be connecting more forms? Is there a reason you can't `Right click > rename` on each sheet?

Comment: Thanks and Yes the plan is to have this collect, organize 100-150 different forms. No issues with right clicking and renaming, just trying to make it easier and learn more about scripts and triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.

**Replace:**

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheet).getActiveSheet();
```

**with:**

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheet).getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").setName("new Name");
```

Or:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheet).getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").setName(formTitle);
```

Comment: Thanks Marios for the quick reply.  still not the result I was hoping for.  Trying to write the sheet name to the destination response and use the form name... this still keeps it in the sheet and my sheet name is still "form response 1". Im going to try some other functions to try and get the name to stick to the tab name!

Comment: Hi there @ScottDroyd! I don't understand why this answer doesn't work in your set up. Could you please clarify it to me? To better understand this scenario please share sample Sheets.

Comment: Yes sir @Jacques-GuzelHeron:
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheet).getActiveSheet();

The script adds the name to the columns...and actually as you submit more it keeps adding more columns with the name!  

I actually want the "tab" in this sheet to be renamed. Instead of the generic form responses 1

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Thanks for sending along!  I've gone through and replaced with your new code but keep getting -  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setName' of null
writeFormTitle @ Code.gs:12. Let me fumble with this a bit and see if I can work it out.

Comment: That error means that in the destination sheet there is no sheet with the name `Form Responses 1`. But I think you said there is one sheet with that name. @ScottDroyd